# Pass function via props cause useEffect infinite loop if I do not destructure props

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a parent component with a state. And I want to pass a handler to set some state from a child component.

This is my parent component.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});

  const setFiltersHandler = useCallback(filtersObj => {
    setFilters(filtersObj);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do something and pass this to <Content /> component 
  }, [filters]);

  return (
    <div>
          <Content filters={filters}>
          <SideBarFilters applyFilters={setFiltersHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my child component. This causes infinit loop.

```
const SideBarFilters = props => {

  const [filterForm, setFilterForm] = useState({
    specialities: {value: "all"}
  });

  // Some code with a input select and the handler to set filterForm

  useEffect(() => {
    let filterObj = {};
    for (let key in orderForm) {
      filterObj = updateObject(filterObj, {
        [key]: orderForm[key]["value"]
      });
    }
    props.applyFilters(filterObj);
  }, [props, orderForm]);


  return <OtherComponent />;
};
```

But if I destructure the props, it does not loop. Like this

```
const SideBarFilters = ({applyFilters}) => {

  // same code as before

  useEffect(() => {
     // same as before
     applyFilters(filterObj);
  }, [applyFilters, orderForm]);


  return <OtherComponent />;
};
```

My guess is that has something to do with how React compare props.
Maybe I should memo all props. But I think that is not a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` object is referentially different each time parent re-renders(and re-renders `SideBarFilters`).

You should not fight that. Trying to find workaround you may run into brand new issues with stale date.

Destructure as you do, it's expected and suggested way to deal with dependencies in hooks.